# How to execute a command in a remote machine and get the output using c#.net

Tags: c#

I am using WMI classes for executing command in remote machine and writing output in a file.
I kept sleep for 5 sec if the process is completes with the 5 sec iam able to get the output from the file.
But if the process is taking more time to finish iam not getting any out put.

Can any one suggest me how to wait till the remote process is completes or any other mechanism to get the output from from remote machine.

Following is my code

```
 ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", computerName), connOptions);
                        manScope.Connect();
                        // Method Options
                        InvokeMethodOptions methodOptions = new InvokeMethodOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue);
                        ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
                        ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
                        // Console.WriteLine(command);
                        inParams["CommandLine"] = "cmd /c " + command + " > c:\\tmp_dr.dat";
                        ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams,methodOptions);

                        Thread.Sleep(5000);

                        // then reading the file.

                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("\\\\" + computerName + "\\c$\\tmp_dr.dat");
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        while (line != null)
                        {enter code here
                            result += line + "\n";
                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                        }



                        sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a WCF service that creates the output to a given file, then returns an object instance that contains information e.g. number of pages in the file (the page size will depend on what you set your buffer size to in the WCF service).

e.g. create an operation contract
Public Function execCommand(Byval commandName as String, Byval outputFile as String) as OutputInfo

Then create a second method that can retrieve the information page by page (possibly returning false when there are no more pages to retrieve or the page is out of range)

Public Function getOutput(ByVal fileName as String, ByVal pageNo as Integer) as OutputPage

Comment: I am new to C#.net. I dont know how to use WCF service. But i want to spawn process in a remote machine and trying to get the output of that process.Can any one help me in this

Comment: You could also use psec http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx to execute the remote process and wait until it terminates before getting the output, or you could simply loop, sleep, check to see if the process is running, until the process terminates. To avoid locking your application you should probably run this in a separate thread. There are lots of references on how to check to see if a remote process is running -e.g http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Check-Remote-Process-is-Running-on-UNIX-Windows-VB6-uTmVNNX3Se.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the way you can wait on the remote process to complete it task

```
uint ProcessId = (uint)outParams["processId"];
    if (ProcessId != 0)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.GetProcessById((int)ProcessId, {your_remoteMachineName});
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch
            {
                break;                    
            }
        }
    }
```